# How to disable current line "highlighting" in emacs (doom emacs)

Tags: emacs

I just installed Doom Emacs, and I get this screen:

[picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmEbq.png)

I'd like for this "highlighting" feature to go away.

I thought it was `hl-line-mode` or `global-hl-line-mode`, but disabling those have no effect.

Using Emacs 27.2 on macOS 10.15.7 on Doom Emacs commit `2731685` (the current head).

Comment: I am not using Doom, but standard Emacs, however `M-x` `hl-line-mode` works for me: it toggles highlighting mode (on/off).

Comment: Right, but this effect doesn't seem to be based off of `hl-line-mode`.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Forcibly change the background color:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
  '(default ((t (:background "#000000"))))
  '(hl-line ((t (:background "#000000"))))
 )
```

add this to the end of `~/.doomd.d/config.el`.

Comment: lol _unspeakably monstrous!_

Answer (score 1):

Doom sets up a variable to control which modes it shows `hl-line`

```
global-hl-line-modes ;; What modes to enable hl-line-mode in.
```

I like to use `hl-line` mode at times, but disliked it appearing as a default so:

```
(setq global-hl-line-modes nil)
```

It should either be a list of modes, or `nil`.

```
;; for example...
(setq global-hl-line-modes '(prog-modes markdown-mode))
```

But for the love of Pete... don't fix this problem with a color change *uurgh!!*.